# Does .NET have a built-in pluralisation mechanism?

Tags: .net, plural

In order to properly handle pluralisation, Qt has [QObject::tr()](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq19-plurals.html), gettext has [ngettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Plural-forms.html), Rails has a good [i18n API](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization), Cocoa has [.stringsdict files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/StringsdictFileFormat/StringsdictFileFormat.html). All those systems take in account the actual number (quantity) to determine the appropriate plural form for a given language.

I know about [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer), [NGettext](https://github.com/neris/NGettext) and [PluralNet](https://github.com/rudyhuyn/PluralNet) but I'm looking for a **built-in** equivalent in .NET. Does it exist or am I out of luck?

Comment: This looks promising but I've not used it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Unfortunately, PluralizationService is only supported for the English language (it throws `NotImplementedException` for other languages). You can also see in its API that it was not designed with other languages in mind since it is only about singular/plural and [many languages have more than those two plural forms](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/cldr-spec/plural-rules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly a built-in solution, but there's a Visual Studio extension, [ReswPlus](https://github.com/rudyhuyn/ReswPlus) (on [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rudyhuyn.ReswPlus)), that leverages [PluralNet](https://github.com/rudyhuyn/PluralNet) and produces methods taking a number as argument to automatically choose the correct plural form for a given localization.

Here's an excerpt from the README about [pluralization](https://github.com/rudyhuyn/ReswPlus#pluralization):

The resources:

```
| Key               | Value            | Comment           |
|-------------------|------------------|-------------------|
| MinutesLeft_One   | {0} minute left  | #ReswPlusTyped[Q] |
| MinutesLeft_Other | {0} minutes left |                   |
```

Will automatically generate the following code:

```
#region MinutesLeft
/// <summary>
///   Get the pluralized version of the string similar to: {0} minute left
/// </summary>
public static string MinutesLeft(double number)
{
    return Huyn.PluralNet.ResourceLoaderExtension.GetPlural(_resourceLoader, "MinutesLeft", (decimal)number);
}
/// <summary>
///   Format the string similar to: {0} minute left
/// </summary>
public static string MinutesLeft_Format(double pluralCount)
{
    return string.Format(MinutesLeft(pluralCount), pluralCount);
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Although it's not built-in, it's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!